# Automatically start jetty when running acceptance tests from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: testing, automation, intellij-idea, jetty

I have a bunch of acceptance tests that need the application to be running. It all works fine when I test from command line (thanks to some gradle magic) but I would like to be able to run these tests from IntelliJ IDEA without worrying about starting up Jetty.

Is there any clever way to achieve that automation? I do not even know where to begin.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can configure Ant/Maven goal that will start Jetty, then create a run configuration for your tests, then configure Ant/Maven to be executed before launch.

Comment: I already have the first part in gradle. Second part - executing it before a test is run from IntelliJ is the problem.

Comment: Before launch doesn't support Gradle yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Maven/Ant, other Run configurations, but not Gradle at the moment, at least until [this feature request is implemented](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86816).

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes it's generally a good idea to use jetty embedded. That way you can fully automate start/stop of jetty and it will work completely independent from build tools/ide.

It's really simple. With few lines of code you have a full featured jetty configured and running for testing.

This is one of the most beloved features of jetty. Have a look at this:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html